# Is it possible to store a python pickle object as a string inside a class?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to do some testing on a feature of my (python) program which is computationally very heavy. I could run the code, store the output in a `pandas.DataFrame`, pickle the `df` and distribute with my package so that the tests can be ran by users. However I think this goes against the principles of unittesting, namely, that a test should be independent of external sources and self contained.

An alternative idea would be if I were to store a pickle file as a string within an importable python class then dynamically write the pickle file and clean it up after the test. Is this possible to do and if so how can I do it?

Here's a small bit of code that simply write a `df` to `pickle.pickle` in the current working directory.

```
import pickle
import os    
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6])
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pickle.pickle')
df.to_pickle(filename)
```

Would it then be possible to somehow get a string version of the pickle so that I can store it  in a class?

Comment: how about read the full file?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it then be possible to somehow get a string version of the
>   pickle so that I can store it in a class?

Just read the full file:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Then if you need you can just unpicle it with `loads`

```
unpickled = pickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: Why not just use `pickle.load`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ he asked to get the string, I just pointed out that he can unpickle from the string too.